# Longest string in a vector — two implementations

Tags: c++, beginner, comparative-review, vectors

I was given this piece of code, which calculates the length of the longest `string` in a `vector` of `string`s:

```
static size_t max_line_length(std::vector<std::string> &lines) {
    size_t max = 0;
    for (auto it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); it++) {
        if (it->length() > max) {
            max = it->length();
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

I am new to C++ with a significant background in Java. If I would write such a function myself, I would come up with something like:

```
static size_t max_line_length(std::vector<std::string> lines) {
    size_t max = 0;
    for (auto line : lines) {
        if (line.length() > max) {
            max = line.length();
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

The difference is in the use of pointers, and the way in iterating the `string`s.

Is there a significant performance difference between these implementations, or are there best practices involved in this?

Comment: The first loop is probably a C++03-era loop. The second one is a C++11 one and is better. However, change `auto` to `const auto&` in the loop, otherwise every line will be needlessly copied.

Comment: @Morwenn Thanks! I have read up on the 'pass by value vs const reference' as well. Does this mean that I should use `const std::vector<std::string> &lines` as well? Also, if you could write your comment in a nice little answer, I can accept it :)

Comment: @Morwenn On second thought, the `vector` would be a constant, but not the `string`s themselves, right? So this would allow the function to manipulate the `string`s, whereas the original method would be pure.

Comment: @Morwenn That comment looks like it should be an answer.

Comment: @200_success I wasn't sure whether the question was on-topic or not (the form seemed strange), so I chose to let a comment instead of answering.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first version of the algorithm uses a traditional C++03-era `for` loop with iterators. The only modern element is the `auto` used to deduce an `std::vector<std::string>::iterator`. The second loop uses a C++11 [range-based `for` loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) whose syntax is close to the one used in Java. The range-based `for` loop is now preferred for several reasons:

- Its terse syntax (when iterators are fully spelled out, a traditional `for` loop is ugly).
- Its genericity: a range-based `for` loop also works with C arrays and `std::valarray`.
- `end` is automatically cached instead of being evaluated at each iteration.

---

That's it for the `for` loops: the range-based `for` loop is preferred. However, there are some things that could be improved in your second version:

- You should pass `lines` as a `const` reference. When you don't need to modify an instance, a `const` reference is good since it avoids a useless copy.
- In your range-based `for` loop, you should write `const auto&` since you don't modify `line` either. It currently performs many useless copies of full `std::string`s just to get their size. Actually, the best thing to write in range-based `for` loops is generally `auto&&`, but the explanation may be [a little complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13230480/1364752) since it involves lvalues, rvalues, `const`-correctness and type deduction.

Answer (score 8):

This is more C++-like:

```
struct size_less
{
    template<class T> bool operator()(T const &a, T const &b) const
    { return a.size() < b.size(); }
};

static size_t max_line_length(std::vector<std::string> const &lines)
{
    return std::max_element(lines.begin(), lines.end(), size_less())->size();
}
```

Comment: What is `Base`? Why use a template? Why not use a lambda? `lines` should be `const`. Free functions `begin` and `end` should be favored over member functions `begin` and `end`. Using the standard library is a very good point though.

Comment: @nwp: Sorry for the `Base`, it was left over from another suggestion I was going to give but then decided not to. I improved the function with `const`, thanks. As for why not lambdas?: because they bloat the generated code for no good reason. Every lambda has a new type, even if it has the same body -- thus every lambda generates new code, which increases compile times and bloats the output file for no good reason. Not to mention that this is C++03-compatible which I prefer (and that's why I didn't use the free versions of `begin` and `end`).

Comment: Lambdas bloat the generated code no more than a `size_less` class created to be used in one specific place and they allow for more expressive local function objects.

Comment: @Morwenn: No, the entire point of `size_less` is that it can be used in more than one specific place. Although I'm sure you already knew this.

Comment: @Mehrdad But will there ever that many places where it will be needed? That's the whole point.

Comment: @Morwenn: Yeah?

Comment: Note that this will segfault if lines is empty